# S-plane poles,zeros to components without table

Tags: analog, filter, laplace-transform

Given N poles and zeroes, how do I find out the circuit element values? And how do I know how they are supposed to sit together (circuit wise)?
For an example, let's say I got a 2nd order analog filter.

```
Zeros = ±i
Poles = -1±i

H(s) = Output(s)/Input(s)

        (s+i)(s-i)
H(s) = -------------
       (s+1+i)(s+1-i)

Output(s)(s+1+i)(s+1-i)=Input(s)(s+i)(s-i)
```

I'm not sure what to do with that information, I know that capacitors become 1/CS and inductors become LS. But I just don't know how to continue down this path. I've done digital filters, but analog filters is something I also want to conquer.

I've seen some matrix-calculations showing how to systematicly recieve H(s) seeing each and every capacitor/inductor as a tiny system (2 pins input, 2 pins output).

And yes, the filter in this example is a very shitty and impractical one.

All I want is a push in the right direction, and I would gladly love if you continued from my example, or made another one.

**EDIT**: I'm talking LC filters, I'm so sorry that I fogot to mention that. The hidden goal is to filter out a huge current (1.6 A) with Cauer filter. Yes it's overkill but at the same time I'm learning.

Comment: There are entire classes dedicated to what you are asking. Mostly likely your filter example can not be implemented using all passive components. Look into a Bi-Quad OpAmp circuit and see if you can make the transfer function fit. You may also be able to translate the circuit into a state diagram and then into an OpAmp circuit.

Comment: This topic is called *filter synthesis*. There is not just one way to implement any particular filter. There are multiple ways to implement it, and you have to choose the best one based on engineering concerns: sensitivity to component variation, cost of components, etc.

Comment: I'm taking the course right now and the teacher is having some problem answering my question, he keeps insisting that I should use tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical procedure is as follows:

1.) Given is the transfer function H1(s) to be realized (for example, derived from required pole-zero locations or from other knowledge sources).

2.) You select one of several realization methods (filter circuits) and the corresponding transfer function H2(s) of the circuit (expressed through parts values).

3.) If both functions H1 and H2 are of the same form (nominal form) you can compare the corresponding polynomial expressions (factors of s and s²). From these equations you can derive formuas for finding the parts values. In nearly all cases you start with a definition of an impedance niveau (choosing a basic R or C value).

**EDIT:** Example to step 3:

For a simple RLC-lowpass (2nd order) the transfer function is

**H2(s)=1/[1+sRC+s²LC]**

From the general system theory we know that any second-order lowpass transfer function (expressed through the pole locations) is:

**H1(s)=Ao/[1+s/(Qp*wp)+s²/wp²]** with Qp=pole Q and wp=pole frequency.

Comparing both functions it is an easy task to see that **LC=1/wp²** and **SQRT(L/C)=R*Qp**. Hence, you have two equations for three unknowns (select L or C). The pole data (Qp, wp) are given parameters (they characterize the lowpass form: Butterworth, Chebyshev,...).

Comment: Are you saying to start with a transfer function, such as a 3 pole low pass Butterworth, and setting it equal to the transfer function for a 3 pole low pass LC circuit, and somehow solve for the circuit element values?

Comment: In principle - yes. However, for a passive 3rd order filter this is an involved task. But you certainly know that this problem was already solved many years ago and - as a result - there are tables (in filter books) which give you all the values (normalized form).

Comment: @2 Name one realization method. @3 "you can derive formuas for finding the parts values". Show me one derivation of a formula for finding the parts values.

Comment: OK - see EDIT in my answer.

Comment: "An involved task" is an understatement. I was hoping you had found a way to simplify it. Oh Well!

Comment: Yes - I like understatements. This is the most efficient method for an overstatement (smiley).

Answer (score 0):

```
Vo          s^2 + 1/(R2R4C1C2)
-- =  ------------------------------
Vi    s^2 + 1/(R1C1)s + 1/(R2R4C1C2)

if R1 = R3
```

This is the characteristic equation that matches your example that can be implemented using a BiQuad.

If you set all your resistors and capacitors to 1 then you get your transfer function. This is not practical to implement. Use magnitude scaling to fix the values. Divide all the capacitors by a set value lets say K to bring all the capacitor values to something reasonable. Then multiply all the resistors by the same K. The magnitude scaling won't change transfer function but will bring the values to something reasonable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffPqVH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

P.S. I'm taking Active Circuits class right now.

Comment: The text you've written is 100% understandable, the values you get, R2R4C1C2 is not. - However I updated my question, I'm interested in LC filters. Sorry for not clarifying it earlier.

Comment: @HarrySvensson What are you having a hard time understanding?

Comment: How do you know that it should be R2R4C1C2 and not R2R4C1C2C3? This information, how you recieved that it was two R values and two C values, that's what would be _very_ interesting. And how you came up with the circuit design. If it's "Oh this is a summator, this is the first pole, this the first zero" - Then I can follow. 

But then again, that's for an active filter, and I'm interested in a passive LC filter.